# Fall Back methods are not called in cloud gateway when a service is down using hystrix and eureka

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, hystrix

I am new to microservices using boot.
I have a project with only 2 microservices (school and student, just a learning project) , I have created the registry service with eureka and the cloud gateway too and all seems to work fine but when I try to stop a service the cloud gateway returns a 405 response status instead of calling the fallback method for the service that is shut down defined in controller.
here is my application.yml for cloud gateway:

```
  application:
    name: API-GATEWAY
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: STUDENT-SERVICE
          uri: lb://STUDENT-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/student/**
          filters:
            - name: CircuitBreaker
              args:
                name: STUDENT-SERVICE
                fallbackuri: forward:/fallback/student
        - id: SCHOOL-SERVICE
          uri: lb://SCHOOL-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/school/**
          filters:
            - name: CircuitBreaker
              args:
                name: SCHOOL-SERVICE
                fallbackuri: forward:/fallback/school
```

Also the controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/fallback")
public class FallBackMethodController {

    @GetMapping("/school")
    public String schoolServiceFallBackMethod(){
        return "School service is taking too long . Retry later.";
    }

    @GetMapping("/student")
    public String studentServiceFallBackMethod(){
        return "Student service is taking too long . Retry later.";
    }
}
```

My pom.xml file :

```
<properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

is something missing here?

Comment: Can you show your versions and dependencies, the hystrix filter is called Hystrix

Comment: @spencergibb I added my pom.xml file

Comment: Hystrix (via spring cloud Netflix 2.2.x) is not compatible with spring cloud 2020.0+. You need to use resilience4j

Comment: @Apex Any solution for this?